# Comparing two summations with different index.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I need to prove the following inequality for those two Summations. However, I am unsure how to tackle this problem :(

$$H_N^{(r)}=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{i^r}<\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{2^k}{2^{kr}}. $$

We have  :

$N = (2^m)-1$

$r > 1$.

I tried developing both summations :

```
 
The H(N) function is the Harmonic serie 1/i^r.
H(2^m - 1) = 1/(1^r) + 1/(2^r) + 1/(3^r) ... + 1/(2^m - 1)^r

Let G = summation(k=0 to m-1) 2^k / (2^kr) = 1/1 + 2/(2^2r) + 2^2/(2^3r)... + 2^(m-1)/2^(m-1)r
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from there (and if developing both summations is necessary in solving this).

I thought about comparing terms by terms, but H(N)'s index is bigger ((2^m) -1) > G(m-1), so I don't think that's the correct way of approaching this.

Any suggestions or resources?

Thank you!

Comment: Please use latex/mathjax to typeset your short formula.

Comment: What about an induction on $ m $?

Comment: hint: $1/4+1/5+1/6+1/7=1/2^2+1/(2^2+1)+1/(2^2+2)+1/(2^2+3)<(1/4)^4$

Comment: @ArnaudMortier : Are we allowed to do an induction with 2 unknown variables?

(ie) Let r = 2

Base case : m = 2

H(3) = 1/1^2 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 = 1+1/4 + 1/9

G(m=2) = 2^0/2^0 + 2^1/2^2 = 1+1/2

1/2 > 1/4+1/9,

So true for m=2. And then i go on with my induction proof?

PS : Is there a way to break line in comments?

Comment: @Robert of course,  then either you have two induction steps (one on each variable) or you have one induction step but an initialisation where the other variable is not specialised. (ie $ r$ is not fixed for the base case).

Comment: @ArnaudMortier : Your name suggests that you can read French, is that the case? If yes, do you think i can show you my proof by induction? 

Thank you :)

Comment: @GCab : I'm not sure I understand your hint :S
I'm trying to see if I can achieve something with ArnaudMortier's induction suggestion. So far, seems like I'm stuck in a dead-end :(

Comment: Is this inequality even true? I use $m = 10, r = 5$, I get LHS = $1.2020564249224905$ and $RHS = 1.0666666666511446$. May be I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my precedent hint
$$
\eqalign{
  & {1 \over {2^{\,n} }} + {1 \over {2^{\,n}  + 1}} +  \cdots  + {1 \over {2^{\,n}  + \left( {2^{\,n}  - 1} \right)}}
 < 2^{\,n} \left( {{1 \over {2^{\,n} }}} \right) = 1  \cr 
  & \quad \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & \left( {{1 \over {2^{\,n} }}} \right)^{\,r}  + \left( {{1 \over {2^{\,n}  + 1}}} \right)^{\,r}  +  \cdots  + \left( {{1 \over {2^{\,n}  + \left( {2^{\,n}  - 1} \right)}}} \right)^{\,r} 
  < 2^{\,n} \left( {{1 \over {2^{\,n} }}} \right)^{\,r}  = {{2^{\,n} } \over {2^{\,r\,n} }}  \cr
  & \quad \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{2^{\,m}  - 1} {{1 \over {i^{\,r} }}}
  = {1 \over {1^{\,r} }} + \left( {\left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,r}  + \left( {{1 \over {2 + 1}}} \right)^{\,r} } \right) +  \cdots  
 + \left( {\left( {{1 \over {2^{\,m - 1} }}} \right)^{\,r}  + \left( {{1 \over {2^{\,m - 1}  + 1}}} \right)^{\,r}  +  \cdots  + \left( {{1 \over {2^{\,m - 1}
  + \left( {2^{\,m - 1}  - 1} \right)}}} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{m - 1} {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2^{\,n}  - 1} {\left( {{1 \over {2^{\,n}  + k}}} \right)^{\,r} } }
  < \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{m - 1} {{{2^{\,n} } \over {2^{\,r\,n} }}}  \cr} 
$$
for $2 \le m$ (for $m=0,1$ it's an equality).

Comment: @ Robert: does it solve your question ?

Comment: @G Cab , sorry, I was busy with my midterms :( 
I'll check it tomorrow and see if i can understand the reasoning behind it and if it solves my problem. Thanks